# Can´t compile with Ant v1.9.4 and JDK8 (CLI)

Tags: ant, java-8

I can´t compile following with `JDK8 & Ant v1.9.4 with CLI`.

`build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="Compile">
    <target name="Compile">
        <mkdir dir="classes"/>
        <javac
            srcdir="src"
            includes="**/*.java"
            destdir="classes"
            source="1.8"
            target="1.8"
            debug="false">
        </javac>
    </target>       
</project>
```

`class`:

```
import sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen;

public class AntProblem {

}
```

`error`:

Buildfile: P:\workspaces\TEST\AntProblem\build.xml
Compile:

```
[javac] P:\workspaces\TEST\AntProblem\build.xml:14: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

[javac] Compiling 1 source file to P:\workspaces\TEST\AntProblem\classes

[javac] P:\workspaces\TEST\AntProblem\src\AntProblem.java:1: error: package sun.security.tools.keytool does not exist

[javac] import sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen;

[javac]                                  ^

[javac] 1 error
```

Of course the package exists and it works within Eclipse, but not with the CLI! I only have this JDK installed, no other version, JAVA_HOME is set to JDK (not the included JRE)!

Any suggestions?

Many thanks and best regards
Wiesi ;)

Comment: I don´t think it´s tools.jar but rt.jar. JAVA_HOME is set to C:/jdk1.8.0_05, therefore Ant uses C:/jdk1.8.0_05/jre. In the subfolder lib I can find rt.jar containing the class sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen ...

Comment: You’re right, it’s in the `rt.jar` but still, it’s no standard API and `javac` does not allow you access to non-standard API. Eclipse shouldn’t as well when you select “Execution Environment” Java-8. Adding `rt.jar` as user class path entry explicitly might help.

Comment: Holger, you might be wrong. It worked with JDK7, and it works with JDK8 if I add the lib-folder of the parallel installed JRE to the classpath (I have C:/jdk1.8.0_05 (JAVA_HOME) and C:/jre8 (classpath-ref) installed). But this environment is not useful on linux machines (f.g. running Jenkins)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that adding `rt.jar` to the classpath manually works. Now you might try adding the `rt.jar` of *the same jdk* to the classpath to complete my suggestion. It doesn’t matter whether the jdk7 compiler did not suppress access to non-standard API. The only thing that matters is that jdk8 does.

Comment: It must be the rt.jar: If I add the one from the JRE to the classpath it works, only using the one from the JDK is not enough, although both containing the package ... :/

Comment: Using the rt.jar from the JDK doesn´t work, same error as submitted in my initial post! The one from JRE does ...

Comment: Adding this to the javac-section solves it: <compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file" />

Comment: So it’s really about using standard API. The jdk contains the file `ct.sym` (the “symbol file” you told it to ignore now) containing the API symbols which the jre does not have (as it is not intended to be a build environment). Without that file, `javac` has to query the `rt.jar` discovering all symbols, including the discouraged ones.